# Do async calls within a function marked with @MainActor also run on the main thread?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, async-await, task

I have a function marked with `@MainActor` that makes an async call, then updates a `@Published` var that will subsequently update the UI. Is the async call blocking on the main thread, or is the updating of the published var the only thing that will be done on the main thread?

```
@Published var users: [User] = []

@MainActor
func getUsers() {
    Task {
        // Is the async call blocking on the main thread here?
        users = await userRepository.getUsers()
    }
}
```

In the above example, is `users` being updated on the main thread, while the async call happening on the `UserRepository` being done in the background? Or, is that async call also being run and blocking on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Task` initialiser

```
Task(priority:operation:)
```

inherits the priority and actor context of the caller, so in your case, as the func is marked `@MainActor`, it will run on the main queue.

`userRepository.getUsers()` runs on another queue, then when it returns your `func` continues back on the main queue.

While it's running the main queue isn't blocked, the func itself is suspended.

Comment: I have upvoted as you capture the basic idea, but I’d suggest avoiding the term “queue”, as we’re not talking about GCD queues here. Perhaps you used the term as a sort of analogy, but it is misleading. The documentation scrupulously avoids the term “queue”. E.g., [`Task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) ”runs the given nonthrowing operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor.“

Answer (score 4):

I know your question has been answered, but I wanted to offer a few clarifying observations.

You asked:

> I have a function marked with `@MainActor` that makes an `async` call, then updates a `@Published var` that will subsequently update the UI. Is the async call blocking on the main thread …

Nothing here will block the main thread. And because your method has been marked with `@MainActor`, the properties it updates will also happen to occur on the main actor, too. (This is a bit brittle, though, because the burden now rests on your shoulders, having to make sure that any methods that happen to update these properties do so on the main actor. But more on that later.)

Technically, we really need to see the `userRepository` implementation to make sure it doesn’t block the current actor. But assuming the “user repository” is not doing something silly like doing some slow synchronous, computationally intensive calculation that blocks the main thread, you should be fine. Also, one should refrain from using any other blocking API, too (such as the C `sleep` function or `Thread.sleep`; though the new [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:)) functions are fine as, unlike traditional “sleep” functions, these are non-blocking).

The key observation, though, is that unlike older “wait” API (such as GCD’s `DispatchGroup`), the Swift concurrency `await` keyword does not, as a rule, block the current thread. The `await` keyword effectively says, “temporarily suspend this function, and free the current thread/actor to go do other stuff until the called `async` function returns a value.”

> … or is the updating of the published var the only thing that will be done on the main thread?

It turns out that this whole method will actually run on the main actor. But there is not much here, though, so that is not a problem. It is just calling an `async` method and then updating some `@Published` property. (In terms of what actor the “user repository” is using, that’s not clear. That is dictated by how that repository was implemented. But as long as the “user repository” doesn't violate that basic Swift concurrency “runtime contract” to not impede forward progress, it does not really matter.)

You go on to ask:

> In the above example, is users being updated on the main thread, while the async call happening on the `UserRepository` being done in the background? Or, is that async call also being run and blocking on the main thread?

There is no “blocking” of the thread. We are “awaiting” a result, and the current thread/actor is free to do other things in the interim.

---

All of this having been said, I might suggest a different pattern. While we have hopefully shown that `await` avoids blocking at all, if your key concern is that you want these `@Published` properties to be published on the main actor, then you want mark those properties as being `@MainActor`. If you do that, then the compiler will ensure that they are updated from the main actor (and generate compilation errors if you ever accidentally attempt to update them from something other than the main actor). It is a more robust way to make sure your published properties happen on the main actor.

Taking this a step further, if you have some class whose primary purpose is to update `@Published` properties for a view, you might mark that whole class as `@MainActor`. Then you do not have to mark all of the individual `@Published` properties with `@MainActor`.

E.g., consider the following:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                Text(user.name)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await viewModel.getUsers()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let userRepository = UserRepository()

    @Published var users: [User] = []            // automatically `@MainActor` because the whole class is

    func getUsers() async {
        users = await userRepository.getUsers()
    }
}

actor UserRepository {
    func getUsers() async -> [User] {
        …
    }
}
```

Now, in the above example, I have made the `UserRepository` an actor. That is not terribly relevant, but it illustrates that repositories, services, managers, etc., do not have to be on the main actor. The key observation is that you may consider just using `@MainActor` for the whole class whose primary role is to publishing property updates for the UI.

Also, as an aside, where possible, I would advise staying within structured concurrency. Note how I started the request in the `.task {…}` modifier. That means that when the view is presented, the request will be initiated, but if the view is dismissed, the request will be automatically canceled for me. When you create a `Task` (e.g., with `Task {…}`), that is unstructured concurrency, with no automatic cancelation. Now, if you are in a non-asynchronous context (e.g., in UIKit or AppKit), then you have to do what you have to do. But with SwiftUI, consider using the `.task {…}` modifier.

---

If you are interested in diving into the Swift concurrency threading model (and the aforementioned “runtime contract”), I might suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/). While we generally want to stop worrying about thread-level details when writing Swift concurrency code, this video provides some insights about some of the clever threading logic going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all the detail! This has been extremely helpful. Will definitely be watching the video you linked to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Swift Concurrency Tasks don't *block* the current thread literally.

A `Task` inherits the execution context from its parent (unless it's a `detached` Task).

Even if `userRepository.getUsers()` runs on a background thread `users` is being updated on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed Apple teaching it this way around instead:

```
// not main actor
class MyClass: ObservableObject {

    @Published var users: [User] = []

    // not main actor
    func getUsers() async {
        // background thread
        let users = await userRepository.getUsers() // should also be background thread if neither the class or func are main actor.
        Task { @MainActor in
            // main thread
            self.users = users
        }
    }
...

// In your View:

.task {
    // main thread
    await myClass.getUsers() // background thread because myClass and getUsers are not main actor.
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/memecreator#Fetching-Panda-Data